# How do I find a sequence that satisfies this limit?

Tags: limits, cubics

I have that $ n(1 - (1 - \frac{1}{x})^3) \rightarrow  \theta $ as $n \rightarrow \infty $ where $\theta$ is a constant. I am trying to find $x$ that satisfies this limit. After expanding the LHS I still cannot find any solutions for $x$. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with $\frac{n}{\theta}$? It looks like that should work - I haven't tried writing out the algebra on paper though....

Comment: @Zestylemonzi: $x$ has to be fixed before you take the limit.  Even so, $n(1-(1-\frac \theta n)^3) \not \to \theta$

Comment: The question makes no sense in that case....$x$ must vary in $n$ otherwise the limit is always $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: Yes $x$ should be in terms of $\theta$ and $n$ @Zestylemonzi

Comment: Hopefully $\frac{n}{\theta}$ works then :) I'll leave the algebra to you.

Comment: @Zestylemonzi Unfortunately I tried $\frac{n}{\theta}$ earlier and it didn't work

Comment: Oops sorry, maybe I forgot a factor of $3$ or something - I'll have a proper look.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such $x$.  For a much simpler case, consider you want to find $y$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}ny=\theta$.  If $y \gt 0,$ the limit is $+\infty$.  If $y=0,$ the limit is $0$.  If $y \lt 0,$ the limit is $-\infty$

Comment: Thanks Ross, that makes sense to me

Answer (score 1):

Subbing in $x = \frac{3n}{\theta}$, your expression expands as

\begin{align*}
n\left(1-\left(1-\frac{\theta}{3n}\right)^3\right) &= n\left(1-\left(1-3\cdot\frac{\theta}{3n} + 3\cdot\frac{\theta ^2}{9n^2} - \frac{\theta ^3}{27n^3}\right)\right)\\
&=\theta - 3\cdot\frac{\theta^2}{9n} + \frac{\theta^3}{27n^2}.
\end{align*}

This gives the limit that you want.

Comment: This seems to work @Zestylemonzi. Thank you for your clear explanation.